# Liking a Photo using FB API and JQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, photo

I am having a problem trying to 'like' a photo using JQuery.  I've tried .post, .ajax, and now using the FB.api post.  When I run the script I don't even get the error messages. This is what I have as a function when the 'like' button is clicked:

```
function like(postId) {
    FB.api('/'+postId+'/likes', 'post', function(result) {
        if (!result) {
            alert('Error: No Response');
        } else if (result.error) {
            alert('Error: '+result.error.message+'');
        } else {
            if (result==true) {
                $('#likeButton-'+postId).hide();
                $('#unlikeButton-'+postId).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions would be a great help as I've been searching through the FB api docs for hours!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to write the function to be defined at parse-time rather than run-time(as the question is formatted)

```
like = function(postId) {
    FB.api('/'+postId+'/likes', 'post', function(result) {
        if (!result) {
            alert('Error: No Response');
        } else if (result.error) {
            alert('Error: '+result.error.message+'');
        } else {
            if (result==true) {
                $('#likeButton-'+postId).hide();
                $('#unlikeButton-'+postId).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function like(postId) {
    FB.api('/'+postId+'/likes', 'post', function(result) {
        console.dir(results);
    });
}
```

And check your browser's console for the complete object and let us know what you see.

Also use your browser's network sniffer to check to see the Response content of the api call.

Comment: it says it can't find the variable: like

Comment: my like button reads: <button onclick="like(\''+this.id+'\');">Like</button>

Comment: ps. shouldn't there be a ); at the end of the FB.api call?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to write the function like: like = function(postId) {....

Comment: Sorry, but in javascript `function like(postId) {` is IDENTICAL to `like = function(postId) {`.

Comment: I guess like = function() is defined at parse-time and the function like() is defined at run-time