# Using Built-in Like in Flash

Tags: flash, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, built-in

With the new Open Graph API, will creating a like button be possible in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been possible for some time. For example: http://labs.byhook.com/2010/08/03/facebook-like-button-in-flash/

There is an AS3 wrapper for the API (basically a set of AS objects which invoke the JS API through ExternalInterface). You can get it here: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

The links on that page are useful as well:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/

http://groups.google.com/group/facebook-actionscript-api

Up-to-date samples can be hard to find for the AS3 API, so it's worth remembering it's just a wrapper for the JS version, for which tutorials can be Googled very easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't think you can "Like" through the AS3-api. Share and lots of connect stuff is possible, but not Like. Or maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: Should be as simple as `Facebook.api("/OBJECT_ID/likes", callback, params, "post");`. Anything you can do in JS, you can do in AS3 - either through the API or through your own `ExternalInterface` calls. (NB: Anything you can *do* - you can't take advantage of pre-built HTML display elements). See here for how to do it through JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921870/liking-a-photo-using-fb-api-and-jquery - there are probably other JS examples on SO.